# Call a function to build drop down list

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I can easily build a drop down using this code:

```
List<SelectListItem> li2 = new List<SelectListItem>();
li2.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Strongly Agree", Value = "5" });
li2.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Agree", Value = "4" });
li2.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Neither", Value = "3" });
li2.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Disagree", Value = "2" });
li2.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Strongly Disagree", Value = "1" });
ViewData["DropDownRatings"] = li2;
```

The problem is I am creating this list in every actionresult for my controller (the CREATE, EDIT and REVIEW actions specifically).

How can I create a function to build this list once, and then just call that function to create the list.  I have tried something like creating this function outside of any controller action, but inside the Class.

```
private CreateRatingsList List<SelectListItem>()  
{
  //Build Ratings List
  List<SelectListItem> li2 = new List<SelectListItem>();
  li2.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Not Rated", Value = null });
  li2.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Strongly Agree", Value = "5" });
  li2.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Agree", Value = "4" });
  li2.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Neither", Value = "3" });
  li2.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Disagree", Value = "2" });
  li2.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Strongly Disagree", Value = "1" });
  //ViewData["DropDownRatings"] = li2;
  return (li2);
}
```

and then I'd like to just have one line of code in each actionresult portion of the controller like:

```
ViewData["DropDownRatings"] = CreateRatingsList();
```

but I can't figure it out.  I'm sure its super simple.  I'm new to MVC, getting the hang of it but still haven't figured this out.

If anyone knows how to do this and can point me in the right direction it will save me some cutting and pasting.

Comment: You just have the signature the wrong way around. `private List<SelectListItem> CreateRatingsList() { ...`

Comment: Thanks Stephen.  You are correct.  I was having a really hard time figuring out what to return (if anything), didnt help I had the signature reversed.  Got it working now, less code, better load time.  Appreciate the quick reply!